# Index match on 2 conditionals?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Data:

[image]

I could use some help coming up with an index match formula based on 2 conditional items. For the attached data set, I need to set up a formula (and make it repeatable for other stores and future dates), that gets the data number based on the specific date (11/9/15, in this case), and for store # 414. In this example, I want "132" to be the answer returned. 
Hope that makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So far you haven't really asked a specific question, just told us what you want.  What have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Why not use... a pivot table?

Comment: I can't use a pivot table b/c I'm pulling from a data clip that refreshes every week, and trying to add values to an existing work sheet.

I've tried something like this, but my formula will return 1,000 since it's taking the first record based on 11/10/14. That's as far as I've gotten.

=INDEX([data set-data],MATCH("414",IF([Data set-Date]="11/9/15",1,[Data set - Store#]),FALSE))

Comment: There are a number of similar previous questions already answered.  A simple approach is to add a helper column that concatenates the first two columns.  Then concatenate your two conditions and match against the helper column.

Comment: Thank you @fixer1234. I haven't had much success looking at previous questions, but I'll keep looking. But obviously, if anyone has any suggestions in the meantime, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Look at the database functions, this is the sort of thing they're for.

Comment: @blm - I'm not as familiar with the database functions, but I'll play around with it. If you know of something specific, that would make things quicker. Thank you!

Comment: Another thought while making lunch :-), is Store # guaranteed to be sorted? If so, you could probably use a couple of `INDEX`es to find the first and last rows for a specific store, then use that to create a reference you pass to `VLOOKUP` to look for the date.

Comment: If you don't want to use a helper column, you can concatenate your criteria inside your `INDEX/MATCH` with `&`. Sort of like `=INDEX([data set-data],MATCH("414"&"11/9/2015",[Data set-Date]&Data set-Store#],0))` (note that this is an array formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions, corresponding to my suggestions in comments on the question. For both of these, I'm assuming A1:C30 contains the data from the question.

**Using a Database Function**

The first solutions uses Excel's database functions. The database functions all treat a range of cells as a database, where each row is a record, and each column is a field. The first row contains the column names. The database functions also take another range of cells as search criteria, where the first row is column names and the second row is the actual criteria. Given that, in E1:F2 (or anywhere, but that's where I've put it for these examples) put:

```
       E         F
 1   Store #     Date
 2       414  11/9/15
```

That's the criteria. Then in E4 (or wherever) put `=DGET(A1:C30,"Data",E1:F2)`. That uses the `DGET` database function to look up a column's value given a database (the `A1:C30`), a column name (`"Data"`), and criteria (`E1:F2`). In this case, that will result in `132`. Changing the contents of F2 to `11/2/15` will change the `DGET` value to `55`, etc.

This is perhaps the cleanest way, because it's easy to extend if you have additional columns in the data and criteria you want to use to match those columns. You can also reuse parts of the criteria to do other things. For example, `=DSUM(A1:C30,"Data",E1:E2)` will sum all the Data values for store 414, `=DSUM(A1:C30,"Data",F1:F2)` will summ all the Data values for 11/9/15, etc. It also doesn't assume anything about the order the columns are sorted in. The downside is that if you don't use the database functions a lot (like me :-) ), you'll have to re-read the help on them every time you use them (like I did for this :-) ), so it's maybe not as maintainable.

**Using Indexing and Lookup Formulas**

The second way combines some of Excel's lookup formulas.

Set up a worksheet the same as above, the data from the question in A1:C30 and the criteria in E1:F2. Note that in this case, we're only going to use E2 and F2, but you can leave E1 and F1 as labels as to what's in E2:F2.

Then in E4, put:

```
 =VLOOKUP(F2,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0),1):INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,1),1),2)
```

Breaking that down, from the inside out:

```
MATCH(E2,A:A,0)
```

That finds the first match (the `0`) in the first column (`A:A`) that matches the store # in `E2`. It returns the relative position, and in this case because all of the first column is the lookup array, the position will be the row number of the first occurrence of the store # in E2. With the example data, if you put this in a cell by itself, it will have a value of `7`.

```
INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0),1)
```

This generates a reference to a cell in the second column (`B:B`) at the row determined by the `MATCH` and column `1`. If you put this in a cell by itself, the value will be the value of the referenced cell, which with the example, will be the value from B7, or `11/10/14`.

```
MATCH(E2,A:A,1)
```

This finds the last match (the `1`) in the first column that matches the store #. If put this in a cell by itself, the value will be `25`.

```
INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,1),1)
```

This generates a reference to a cell in the third column (`C:C`) at the row determined by the `MATCH` and column `1`. If you put this in a cell by itself, the value will be the value of the referenced cell, which with the example, will be the value from C25, or `132`.

```
INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0),1):INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,1),1)
```

This combines the two `INDEX` formulas to generate a reference to search for the date. With the example data, it will be B7:C25 (if you put it in a cell by itself, you'll get a `#VALUE!` because it results in more than one value. If you put it in a cell by itself as an array formula, you'll get the upper-left cell's value, or `11/10/14`).

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0),1):INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,1),1),2)
```

This combines it all. It uses `VLOOKUP` to look for the date from `F2`, in the cell range generated by the two `INDEX` formulas (B7:C25), and to return the second column (the final `2`) on the matching row.

Voilá!

Comment: That vlookup/index match worked perfectly! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! One quick question. If I was to add another column of data, and insert it in column "D", how would my the formula change? I seem to be getting an error when I try to change which columns the formulas lookup to. Thank you again!

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out! I changed C:C to D:D and then added the column lookup in my 2nd index match formula from 2 to 3! Voilá!

Comment: @Matt Cool, glad you got it working and were able to extend it.